# Why did my question not get answers but instead critical comments?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions

This question is related to an account ban.

In other topics, I read that I needed to avoid being a help vampire.

So, I searched Google, modified code according to tutorials/advices, and then tried the code which did not work. I am not able to understand why and hence, asked my question.

Possibly my question is stupid however, I needed to know how to modify code.

Unfortunately, instead of answers, I got comments [as to why such coding is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394750/how-to-extract-certain-values-from-an-array). I followed the advice  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?). I showed a sample of code, wrote what I tried, etc.

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing this... I understand you're commenting on an account ban, but from there, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to convey.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question you asked that was giving you issues? Looks like you only have 3 questions on SO, none of which have the type of comments you're mentioning here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394750/how-to-extract-certain-values-from-an-array Where is problem with the question? I do not understand

Comment: @Rachel It's really hard to figure out what he's even asking here, he didn't actually link to the question that he had problems with.  Does he want to know why he's account banned, does he want to know why someone would post a comment on his question, what problems does he have with those comments, which comment(s) does he have this issue with, etc.  It's simply a low quality meta question.  Low quality questions tend to be (justifiably) downvoted.

Comment: In such case I want to know how to distinguish low quality from average/good quality. Is there a link to some checklist?

Comment: @user2360838 The how to ask page ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ) is chock full of the same things we're telling you here. If you want the cliff notes version for your specific issue, see my answer. In general though, that link provides everything you need.

Comment: Unless some of the comments have been deleted, I can't see what's wrong with them. People asked you for clarifications, especially the last one sounds very relevant ("And how do you define these "certain values"? Is there a common property to them or is it purely a matter of which index in the array it is?"). If there's a problem here it's that for some reason you didn't answer these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well pretty simple.  One of the comments explains it all.

> Have you actually tried anything so far?

You took an example.

- I have this
- I want that
- How ?

Instead of saying I tried doing this *this way*. I encountered a problem which is. Here are *my traces of tries i've made*. Now can somone help me ?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything so far? Of course! $output = array_slice($input, 0, 1); This is the direction / way I went. It does not work. Question may be stupid for experienced coders. I am not experienced. So I ask. Or, ok. What (what way) I needed to try? I searched google with keywords (phrases) that came in my mind. No answer/solution

Comment: @user2360838 See my answer. People are asking you *why* you need everything in one variable, and what the task you're trying to accomplish is.  Those are great questions, they provide context.  Edit your question to include the context, and there shouldn't be any issue about its value.

Comment: But here I wrote why Must manage (process) only certain values (elements) from array. Comment below. Actually I do not want to complaint. I want to understand where is problem... I need answer and I ask. I am not allowed to ask some kind of questions? How to distinguish what allowed and what not.

Comment: @user2360838 I think we're having a communication issue here. You're allowed to ask questions, but you have to work with us. When people are asking the reason why you want to do something a certain way, it's so they can help you. If someone asks,  "I want to hammer my toe, how do I do that with a screwdriver?" wouldn't you ask them "Why do you want to do that?"

Comment: @user2360838 Answering why you need the solution has several benefits. It often gives a more clear picture of the problem and more suitable answers (in this case, for example, is the array always the same length?). Sometimes it lets people give better answers that solve the actual problem differently or more efficiently. Turning the question other way around, is there a reason why you feel so strongly that you don't want to give any background information?

Comment: Ok. Will take in mind that need to write what aim want to reach...

Answer (score 14):

Oftentimes, *why* is the most important question of all.

Don't discount it when people ask you *why*.  If you tell us why you're doing something, we might be able to tell you a better way, or to help you solve a problem idiomatically.

[In this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394750/how-to-extract-certain-values-from-an-array), you're being asked, *Why do you need to do it this way? (put three variables into one)*" What task are you trying to accomplish?

If you edit your question to include this information, it can help us solve your problem (And make your question better, to boot).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I need to say loud and clear I *applaud* your research effort in learning how to ask a good question on SO.

Next I want to clearly emphasize that asking good questions may actually be *quite* difficult.  We do everything we can to be clear on our standards but there is also a bit of a culture that legitimately takes a bit to get the hang of.

Here are some resources to start:

- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/ask)
- [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- Please read carefully any close-vote reasons you get or see
- [Jon Skeet, SO's #1 answerer's, take, or one of them](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

But yes, if you are still "stumped" asking on meta is a very good thing to do.  Ideally you won't have to do it too often once you get the hang of things.

There are many more.  I don't know if there is a canonical list on meta; if not, I'll start one.